# How to set an attribute inside the underscore.js _.each, initialized outside

Tags: javascript, google-maps, underscore.js

Here is my code:

```
var total_dist = 0;
_.each(arguments, function (value, index) {
    var directions_display = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    directions_display.setMap(self.map);
    self.directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                directions_display.setOptions({
                    polylineOptions: {
                        strokeColor: '#35C4BB'
                    }
                });
            }
            // Parse string distance to float (ex: '5,4 km' -> 5.4)
            var str = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
            str = str.split(" ");
            str = str[0].split(",");
            str = parseFloat(str.join("."));
            total_dist += str;
            console.log(total_dist) // it shows a float > 0 it s fine
            self.get_routes_total_distance(total_dist);
            directions_display.setDirections(response);
        } else if (status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
            alert('ERROR when displaying routes: Some partners cannot be localized.');
            // self.on_add_polyline(paths);
        } else {
            window.alert(_t('Directions request failed due to ' + status));
        }
    });
});
console.log(total_dist) // it shows 0 ! why???
```

Well, I initialize the `total_dist` outside the `_.each`. Then I set its value inside when I did `total_dist += str`.
When I `console.log` the `total_dist` inside the `_.each`, it shows a value >0 (its been set).
But when I `console.log` it outside the `_.each`, it shows 0.

So how can I set the `total_dist` inside the `_.each` so that I can use it outside?

**EDIT (minimal version)**

```
routes = [10,5,6];
var total_dist = 0;
_.each(routes, function (value, index) {
    total_dist += value;
console.log(total_dist); // it shows 21 (inside _.each)
}

display(total_dist); // here, outside _.each, total_dist = 0

display : function(distance){
    alert(distance);
};
```

So I want to try to set the total_dist inside the _.each and use it (value set) outside

Comment: The _.each functions run asynchronously, the variable **is** being updated, just after the `console.log` runs

Comment: BTW - you might want to use the `distance.value`, that is in meters, but is a number that can be more easily accumulated.

Comment: I see! Good to know. I will see about the distance in meters then. Thank you very much !! So what do you suggest me to do if I want to use the variable outside the _.each?

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] I could provide a working example.

Comment: ok I ve done a minimal edit above. I hope it helps you understand my problem. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Underscore.js documentation [examples](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce), `reduce` is what they use to do exactly what you want, a `sum`

So you could do the following:

```
routes = [10,5,6];
var total_dist = _.reduce(routes, function(memo, route, index) {
   // index is the index of route in routes
   return memo + route;
}, 0);

display(total_dist);

display : function(distance){
    alert(distance);
};
```

**Update**: The third parameter passed by `_.reduce` is the *index*

Comment: Good to know!! I ll try it! BTW Do you know how to get the index of 'routes' with _.reduce?  Thank you !!!

Comment: Yes, the third argument is the index, I've updated the post to illustrate

Comment: Thank you very much wjvander !!